# Limit proof going to infinity $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Using the definition, prove that limit of $$\dfrac{\sin x}{x^2}$$ as $x\to\infty$ and find its limit.

So far, I have found that by the Squeeze Theorem the limit=$1$. As for the proof...

Let $ε > 0$ be given. Set $M=1/ε$. If $x > 0$, then $$|(\sin(x)/x^2)-0|= \sin x/x^2 > M => (x^2/\sin x) < 1/M <ε.$$

I'm not sure if I am doing something "illegal" with flipping the $\sin x/x^2$?

Comment: The limit shall be zeroes.

Comment: You've done nothing "illegal" (except where $\sin x=0$), but you didn't prove anything yet.

Answer (score 3):

If $0<a<b$ then $\frac1a>\frac1b$ is equivalent. But I don't see your proof. Since sinus is not positive for $x>0$ it is wrong to say $|\sin(x)|=\sin(x)$.

Hint: $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ is true for all $x\in\mathbb R$, so $\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}\right|\leq\frac1{x^2}$. Now you might see what happens to the limit and how to prove it?

Comment: So @MundronSchmidt, from there we are basically proving the limit of 1/x^2...is this kind of using the Comparison Thm?

Comment: So, I have: Since |sin(x)|≤1, then |sin(x)/x^2|≤1/x^2. Set M=1/ε. Then, if M>0, |1/x^2-0| = 1/x^2 < 1/M < ε. Thus, |sin(x)/x^2|≤ ε. Is this correct>

Comment: It is almost fine, but you use $\frac1{x^2}<\frac1M$ and you never declared a relation between $x$ and $M$. You might think of using $x>M$ then you get $\frac1{x^2}<\frac1{M^2}$ and for a good choice of $M$ you can conclude $\frac1{M^2}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

$|\sin(x)| \le 1.$

Let $x >1:$

$|\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^2}| \le \dfrac{1}{x^2} \lt \dfrac{1}{x}.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Let  $M$, real, positive, be such that $M>1/(\epsilon).$

For $x \gt M :$

$|\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^2}| \lt \dfrac{1}{x} \lt  \dfrac{1}{M} \lt \epsilon.$